# Am i sick enough to not fast?

Tags: ramadan

Salaam, ramadan kareem

So i am a thirtheen year old boy that tried to fast everyday. the last few days i was sick so i couldn't fast. now i have a bit of a stuffy nose and an weird feeling  in my throat. my immune system is of course not 100% developed and i'm scared that if i fast i will get worse. So is it halal for me to not fast today? for example i am very thirsty and hungry (i feel like i'm going to throw up) and haven't been 12 pm yet!

Best regards

Comment: We are not a fatwa site. If you need a Fatwa you should ask a scholar on the net you won't get an answer that soon even on fatwa sites it would take weeks for an answer. The question is rather is fast a due on you as at the age of thirteen not all people are mature.

Answer (score -1):

Yes you can skip your fasting and complete the count later any time of year.

Comment: On what basis? See [answer] and consider supporting your claims with evidences.